# How to update a record in salesforce using a link which sent in an email template?

Tags: email, email-template, update

use case

I need to send an email to all my contact stating that We have following information of urs in our production instance.
User will decide whether they want to keep that information with us or not. 
Need to provide them two options Keep Archive if they click on any of these option automatically contact record within salesforce should get update.

Comment: I don't know if you can directly do it from email. One way is to send link in your email, which will open the force.com site from where user can update the record

Answer (score 0):

Archive and Keep can be two separate links on the email and behind the scenes you can configure these links in such a way that you pass relevant parameter when either is clicked.

For example, when you click Archive, the following URL can open - `https://*.salesforce.com/apex/ContactPage?actionType=Archive`

ContactPage is your VF page where you can put essential logic to either archive or update the Contact. Your Visualforce controller can fetch the passed parameter and process necessary actions. You can also show a custom message at the end of operation or maybe close the tab using JS.

Edit:
However, it is important to give this user unauthenticated access to Salesforce so you will have to use Site.

Answer (score 0):

As "salesforce Developer" commented, a [Force.com Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) is a way to provide unauthenticated access to the email recipient. (I'm assuming that the email recipients don't have a login in your org.) So the URL will need to have this sort of makeup:

```
https://.../xyz/ContactPage?action=Archive&id=003000000000123&token=md1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2Yg
```

where "xyz" identifies the site, you pass in the Contact Id (as this being an unauthenticated request the code doesn't know who is making the request and so can't identify the relevant Contact) and you also include an encrypted token to ensure that the request is a valid one and not one being made by a hacker.

(Or you can encode all the information in the encrypted field and also include a timestamp so the access time window is limited to e.g. 48 hours. See e.g. https://jwt.io/ for the principles.)